# Which modulation is suitable for OFDM sub-channels?

Tags: digital-communications

As we all know, OFDM consists lots of sub-channels and different sub-channels can be modulated in different way independently. So among OOK, ASK, BPSK, MPSK, QAM, FSK, MSK, which methods are suitable for modulation of sub-channel?

Answer (score 1):

You're question is a bit open ended. In general, the most suitable scheme would be the one most efficient scheme, or one that provides the least bit error for your power requirements and transmission channel.

For 802.11 (common ethernet), there are 52 sub channels, and in general uses binary phase shift keying (BPSK) for sub channels.

http://rfmw.em.keysight.com/wireless/helpfiles/89600b/webhelp/subsystems/wlan-ofdm/Content/ofdm_80211-overview.htm

Comment: "The possible data subcarrier modulation formats are BPSK, QPSK, 16QAM, and 64QAM." So that means OOK FSK won't be appied in practice. Is there any theoretic reason or support for this?

Comment: For OFDM to work as advertised, you need a modulation scheme that transmits a pure sine wave at the nominal carrier frequency during each symbol. The only degrees of freedom left are phase and amplitude, which may be changed instantly at symbol boundaries.

Comment: In comparison to the mentioned modulation schemes, OOK FSK has a much lower bit-rate. It's probably the simplest lowest rate you could use, which is why it's not a preferred method.

Answer (score 0):

Think about parts of the radio frequency spectrum being a bunch of individual carriers that are identified by their position in that spectrum i.e. frequency division multiplexing. There is no theoretical reason why any form of modulation couldn't be used for any individual channel. Going back to the RF analogy, AM stations could sit close by (but seperated from) FM channels. Providing the bandwidth occupation of one channel doesn't leak into a co-channel any modulation type could be used.